# None of [Index([], dtype='object')] are in the [columns] - pd.merge error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having problems when Im trying to merge two dataframes. Here is an example of dataframe structures.

DataFrame 1:

```
code name 
1    billy 
2    gary
3    fred
```

DataFrame 2:

```
code valeu date 
1    2      05/25
2    3      06/26
5    4      07/27
```

I want to get an result like this:

```
code value date  name
1    2     05/25  billy
2    3     06/26  gary
5    4     07/27
```

This is the code that gave me this error message:

```
result = pd.merge(base_platinum[['Número da ADE', 'Operador']], backoffice[['Adesão', 'Operador']], left_on='Número da ADE', right_on='Adesão', how='left')
```

This is the error message:

> `KeyError: "None of [Index(['Adesão', 'Operador'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Yes, I created a situational example. But I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'billy'], [2, 'gary'], [3, 'fred']
], columns=['code', 'name'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, '05/25'],
    [2, 3, '06/26'],
    [5, 4, '07/27']
], columns=['code', 'valeu', 'date'])

df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='code')
print(df3)
```

prints

| index | code | valeu | date | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 05/25 | billy |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 06/26 | gary |
| 2 | 5 | 4 | 07/27 | NaN |

Comment: Trying for multi column unique match on left and right to get the columns 'B', 'val' of df2 into df1, getting the same error. Any tips? 
`big_df = pd.merge(
    left=df1,
    right=df2[['id','A', 'B', 'val']],
    left_on=['id','A','B'],
    right_on=['id','A','B'],
    how='left'
)`